# Install Ubuntu on my laptop that has Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

My question is how to install Ubuntu 15.10 to my laptop that has Windows 10 without replacing my documents and all my information.
I tried to make a boot on my USB, but my application for the boot doesn't recognize it, it sends me an error that it doesn't have the files and I need to download them. The files are "ldlinux.sys" and "ldlinux.bss".

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS? If system has Windows 10 pre-installed it will be UEFI. And then you want to boot from UEFI boot menu the Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode not BIOS. The lslinux.sys is from syslinux which is the BIOS boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu you're going to have to make a back up of all documents you want to keep. After installing Ubuntu you can then copy the documents to your Ubuntu install.

The reason why the USB pen isn't bootable might be because the Ubuntu ISO hasn't been burned correctly onto the USB pen. A search for "windows burn iso" should give you plenty of information about how to burn an ISO.

Answer (score 0):

What software did you use to import Ubuntu on your USB flash drive? Sometimes the bootable usb creators use their own syslinux and cause problems. I recommend burning the ISO file to a disk and load it from the boot menu. This should fix the problem. Also, unless you have your files on another hard drive or partition, if you install Ubuntu it will remove everything on your system.

What you are trying to do is risky; you should backup all your data. If it's not possible, then create a another partition, install Ubuntu on it. Then, copy your files that you have on your windows partition to your Ubuntu partition using file manager. Finally, you can decide whether to remove Windows or keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the software named *Universal USB creator* to create a bootable USB drive .

Making a dual boot for Ubuntu and windows is sometimes a problem as the various different file systems such as swap and ext4 are required.

Option 1:
Run the installer , if it shows *Install alondside Windows* , then you're golden.

Option 2:
-Use a software called *Acronis* to backup windows (Image file is 15~20 GB)
-Store the backup in an external drive
-Install Ubuntu on the full disk
-Install Ubuntu again on the smaller disk size you want to allocate
-Delete the older Ubuntu (format that partition) . Install windows there ,and create the partitions
-Install a fresh windows again 

-Recover your old version using *Acronis* again . You won't even spot any difference between
  your  old and new window.
-If the bootloader gives a problem , use a software named *EasyBCD*